# Gradle files not uploaded on GitHub

Tags: android-studio, github

I faced some stange problem, when I try to share my project on GitHub from Android Studio it uploads without any Gradle data, pls see attached image for details. And there is the only one project where I such kind of problem, all other uploaded correctly. I'm at a loss.

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wUsz.png)

Comment: What is the error you're facing while uploading the files?

Comment: Are the files being ignored due to .gitignore?

Comment: Once o got this: "Can't connect to repository from configured remote. You could want to check .git config."